# What is a www10 address?

Tags: http, https, dns

I found this website:

http://www10.fintrac-canafe.gc.ca/msb-esm/public/msb-search/search-by-name/

And noticed a 10 after the typical www. I never seen this before; what is it? When does it get used? What does it mean? It's not even using https, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I never seen this before; what is it?

A name.

> When does it get used?

When someone wants to name something that way.

> What does it mean?

There's no convention giving a particular common meaning to that name.

> It's not even using https, why?

Because the people running the site didn't set up HTTPS.

Comment: The website `http://www.fintrac-canafe.gc.ca/` doesn't have the 10, does that mean the first one I posted (with a 10) is a fraud/fake? Or they are both the same domain? Weird that a government website doesn't use https

Comment: There are `www.google.com` and `mail.google.com` and `maps.google.com`... does that mean that the last two are fake? And yes, it is kind of weird that government website doesn't use https (or ANY site, for that matter)